# Is it possible to have two property in one string.join() and how to do looping in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

**My first problem**

is it possible to do like this ? this code didn't have any runtime error just id didn't prompt the output

```
 public string IdSubDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("\n", IdSub, ItemQuantitySub);
        }
        set { }
    }
```

currently I'm doing it one by one.

```
public string IdSubDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("\n", IdSub);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public string QuantitySub
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("\n", ItemQuantitySub);

        }
        set { }
    }
```

their property is like this

```
 public int[] IdSub { get; set; }
 public decimal[] ItemQuantitySub { get; set; }
```

if you curious why I do like this. Actually I have this code

```
List<int>Ids = itemRelationBO.GetItemRelationItem(item.ItemId);
List<decimal> itemSubQty = new List<decimal>() {1};

      Display display = new Display()
          {
            IdSub = Ids.ToArray(),
            ItemQuantitySub = itemSubQty.ToArray()
          };

        itemDisplayList.Add(display);
```

**My second problem is for the looping**

let say in `Ids` there are 2 `item`, so I want the `ItemQuantitySub` loop for two time. the `ItemQuantitySub` will always havevalue `1` as an output meanwhile the `Ids` is call from database. So if the `Ids` have 5 items in it, the `ItemQuantitySub` will have 5 items too
like this

```
Ids       |     Quantity
----------|--------------
212       |       1
132       |       1
```

currently my output like this

```
 Ids       |     Quantity
----------|--------------
212       |       1
132       |
```

the output `ItemQuantitySub` only display once.

I try to do String.Join() that combine both properties to make the output like I want as shown above. I didn't have any idea to do what I want.so I'm trying to do like the above String.Join().

Comment: If `ItemQuantitySub` is always one, why bother defining this property at all? And if it's just one (single number), why wasting memory to allocate whole decimal array??? Question is completely unclear for me.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn no I means `ItemQuantitySub` value always 1. so if the `Ids` have 3 items, the quantity should also have 3 items. so it like looping.

Comment: It's still unclear, what are those tables? You want to update them? Then ask another question regarding SQL. Or you want it to display as a table? Question becomes too broad. Ask another one, where you will explain more clearly what problem is, rather asking one question with doezn of problems, where each isn't explained very well.

Answer (score 0):

(Just guessing...) return this in your property:

```
string.Join("\n", IdSub) + "\n" + string.Join("\n", ItemQuantitySub);
```

Comment: @raynaqarla I don't see second problem in your question. What is it?

Comment: sorry if its unclear, I've try my best to explain it . I've updated my question